# Как полностью отображать placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Если поле ввода имеет длинный **placeholder**, то как сделать, что бы оно отображалось полностью, а не обрезалось?

Код:

```
<input id="m" onkeydown="userIsTyping()" placeholder='Type your message here. Use "private to {nickname}:" to send private message. ' autocomplete="off">
```

Весь код: https://github.com/Eramik/webdev-study-socket-chat/blob/master/node/index2.html

Comment: увеличить размер поля?

Comment: Добавьте немного кода, который внесет ясность в Ваш вопрос.

Comment: https://github.com/Eramik/webdev-study-socket-chat/blob/master/node/index2.html
Там весь код. Увеличить поле в каком смысле? А если это устройство с маленьким экраном?

Comment: Значит уменьшите шрифт, плейсхолдер тоже уменьшится

Comment: шрифт и так не большой. Меньше будет не читабельный

Comment: как по вашему должна решаться эта проблема?

Comment: вопрос из разряда "как вместить арбуз в кофейную кружку"... либо уменьшайте текст, либо увеличивайте инпут. это же очевидно) либо используйте тултип (tooltip), он как раз для таких целей имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сколько процентов длины `placeholder` будет показано - зависит от размера поля и управляется браузером.
У маленького поля большой текст обрежется в любом случае, это логично.
Можно, разве что, [стилизовать подсказку](http://html5.by/blog/placeholder/).

Comment: Заходил через Microsoft Edge и через хром. Всё последней версии, а не отображает примеры на сайте, как они были задуманы.

Comment: @Erami, я через хром заходил, и через FF, и через оперу (тот же `Blink`) - всё работает и отображается.

Comment: Хотя бы пример с эллипсом, который как раз для меня

Comment: Попробуйте поставить стиль и использовать `::-ms-input-placeholder` префикс. Именно `::`, а не `:`. Говорят в `Edge` помогает.

Comment: Мне едж особо не нужен, главное хром. http://prnt.sc/b3lyyq

Comment: @Erami, всё работает. Без свойства, текст некрасиво обрезан. С ним - красиво поставленные точки.

Comment: Я думал будет более эффективное решение :D
Всё равно спасибо.

Comment: @Erami, что Вы имеете ввиду под "более эффективным решением"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно через JS получать длину строки `placeholder` и если изменять ширину `input` под длину текста.